# Need to add empty space using StreamReader

Tags: c#, streamreader

I am reading all the files, using StreamReader and i need to insert empty space at the end of each line.

For Example : Consider below case, are the data in file.

1. File.........................................................................
2. New..........................................................................
3. Text.........................................................................
4. .............................................................................

In the dotted area, i need to include empty spaces. How can this be done?

Comment: It is really unclear what you're asking. Show example input, output, code and what you have tried.

Comment: I have updated the details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question, but, if the goal is to add spaces after any line , you can calculate the length of your line and then use this code to fill your line with the spaces needed :

```
var streamReaderFileName = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.Default);
var streamWriterNewName = new StreamWriter(newName, false, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
yourLine = streamReaderFileName.ReadLine();
while (yourLine!=null)
{
yourLineLength = yourLine.Length;
yourNewLine = yourLine.PadRight(yourLineLength + numberOfSpaceYouWant)
yourLine = streamReaderFileName.ReadLine();
}
streamWriterNewName.WriteLine(yourNewLine);
streamReaderFileName.Close();
streamWriterNewName.Close();
```

If you give us more info, maybe I could help better :)

Comment: It is what i want. But, i would like to know, how to define number Of Space to be added. For example.

1) Text......................................................................................................
2) Text1 Text2 Text3Text4.......................................................................
3) EmptyLine............................................................................................

in this above case, each line has different length of text and in some line, there will not be text.

Comment: For those cases, i would like to calculate and fill empty spaces till the end of line. Hope this helps, :)

Comment: If your line must always be for a fixed number of spaces, you can calculate the number of spaced you need to fill : 

`MaxLengthLine = 70;
yourNewLine = yourLine.PadRight(MaxLengthLine -yourLineLength);`

Using this sample, you will always have a line with 70 chars :)

Otherwhise, you need to calculate the number of space you want to add comparing the text in your streamreader to a string.

I don't have another solution in mind for now.